# trying auto play video using bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i m trying to create video slider using bxslider plugin. slider is working fine. but i need video to be auto play when page loads. i add following lines in js.

```
jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  video: true,
  useCSS: false,
  autoplay:true
 });
```

and i use iframe tag inside unsorted list tag having class=bxslider.
I also add ?autoplay=1 after video url as follows

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/17914974?autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen ></iframe></li>

  <li><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aTLRdrRQyN4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
</ul>
```

but no solution
any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

change `?autoplay=1` to `?rel=0&autoplay=1` at the end of your link that should work

```html
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/17914974?rel=0&autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: it doesnt work!!!!!i m not able to grab issue in it. actually when page loads the video play button appears and at 2nd second again stops and video is just buffering only